# Maven / JavaScript Project

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, maven

Currently I am working on a JavaScript application and I am trying to build it as modular as possible. What I'm planning to do is to get a folder structure like

```
js
|__ controllers
|__ services
|__ directives
index.html
```

I am using angularjs and i want to split all the controllers and services into seperate files.

I am a Java-Developper and I want to use maven to build this project and deploying it on a tomcat.

In production mode i want to a compressor/obfuscator to pack all files into one single `application.js`. Normally when I build my projects i only got one file for all controllers and one for all services and so on. So what I am doing is have one profile for `dev` and one for `live` and with filtering I append `.min.js` in my index.html to include all the files ( minimized on live, non-minimized on dev )

Finally my question:

What is the best way to do that with multiple files?

In development mode i want

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="MyFirstController.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="MySecondController.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="MyThirdController.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="MyFirstService.js">
/* ... */
```

And in production mode i only want one file included in my `index.html`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myapp.js">
```

The first solution but clearly a not very pretty solution would be to have a multiline property in my maven file where i got all the script tags which i then replace with filtering.

I hope someone can tell me a good solution for my problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI, combining them like that may actually do more harm than good, especially when taking caching into account and when using HTTP/2 or SPDY where you can send all the files multiplexed over a single connection.

Comment: I thought about that too. Nur its possible that there are ~70 controllers in this project. And including 70 js files... I dont think that brings a great performance with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin). This is useful if you want to bundle scripts with a maven artefact.

I haven't needed to use this because my javascript code has been an entirely separate deployable (decoupling and all that). So this is a good use case for gulp. Take a look at the `gulpfile.js` from [hottowel](https://github.com/johnpapa/generator-hottowel).

First take a look at the build task and its dependencies:

```
/**
 * Build everything
 * This is separate so we can run tests on
 * optimize before handling image or fonts
 */
gulp.task('build', ['optimize', 'images', 'fonts', 'test-server'], function() {
    log('Building everything');

    var msg = {
        title: 'gulp build',
        subtitle: 'Deployed to the build folder',
        message: 'Running `gulp serve-build`'
    };
    del(config.temp);
    log(msg);
    notify(msg);
});
```

These should do most of the things you want. There are also environment specific gulp tasks:

```
gulp serve-dev
gulp build
```

There are a lot more in there so take a read through.

I've also worked on java + angular projects and it was handy for deployment and consistent with the java/maven approach to create artefacts for the javascript code that can be stored on nexus and fetched for deployment when needed.

The artefact for the javascript code is just a zip file which I create with the following gulp task (ignoring directories and files with `!` in front of the directory name):

```
/**
 * Create a versioned artefact
 */

    gulp.task('generate-artifact', function() {
        var filename = getFilename();
        return gulp
            .src([
                './**/*.*',
                '!artifacts/',
                '!artifacts/**',
                '!build/',
                '!build/**',
                '!node_modules/',
                '!node_modules/**',
                '!bower_components/',
                '!bower_components/**'
                ])
            .pipe($.tar(filename + '.tar'))
            .pipe($.gzip())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./artifacts/'));
    });
```

Then to deploy to nexus using the [nexus-deployer](https://github.com/cthorne66/nexus-deployer/) plugin:

```
/**
 * Deploy release to nexus
 */ 
gulp.task('deploy-release', ['clean-pomdir'], function(cb) {
    var deployer = require('nexus-deployer');
    var filename = getFilename();
    var pkg = require('./package.json');

    log('Retrieving artifact ' + filename + '.tar.gz' + 'from artifacts dir');
    log('Deploying version ' + pkg.version + ' of ' + pkg.name);

    var release = {
        groupId: 'my.group.id',
        artifactId: 'my-artefact',
        version: pkg.version,
        packaging: 'tar.gz',
        auth: {
            username: args.username,
            password: args.password
        },
        pomDir: config.pomDirReleases,
        url: 'http://path-to-nexus.repo',
        artifact: './artifacts/' + filename + '.tar.gz',
        noproxy: '',
        cwd: ''
    };

    deployer.deploy(release, cb);
});
```

There are a few custom methods and config things in there too: the great [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) module to pass in username and password as command line arguments; convenience method in `gulpfile.js` to get the filename:

```
function getFilename() {
    var pkg = require('./package.json');
    var filename = pkg.name + '_' + pkg.version;
    return filename;
}
```